# Is it possible to register a call-back URL in Twilio messaging service via REST API?

Tags: twilio

I would like to know whether a call-back URL can be registered via REST API? If so can I get the API document?

This [document](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request) says it can be done. But the actual API information is not listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the incomingPhoneNumber API endpoint.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource

Look at the update code examples, to
understand the syntax.